# Problem with a button

Tags: android, button, onclick

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20px"
            >
        <Button android:id="@+id/expandButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" + " 
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:clickable="false"
                />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/jokeTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16px"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/ratingRadioGroup"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/likeButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60px"
                    android:text="Like"
                    />
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/dislikeButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60px"
                    android:text="Dislike"
                    />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have class extends View(LinearLayout)

```
import ...

    public class JokeView extends LinearLayout{

        private Button m_vwExpandButton;
        private RadioButton m_vwLikeButton;
        private RadioButton m_vwDislikeButton;
        private RadioGroup m_vwLikeGroup;
        private TextView m_vwJokeText;
        private Joke m_joke;

        public static final String EXPAND = " + ";
        public static final String COLLAPSE = " - ";

        public JokeView(Context context, Joke joke) {
             super(context);
             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
                      Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.joke_view, this, true);

        m_vwExpandButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.expandButton);
            m_vwLikeButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.likeButton);
            m_vwDislikeButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.dislikeButton);
            m_vwLikeGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.ratingRadioGroup);
            m_vwJokeText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.jokeTextView);

            setJoke(joke);
                collapseJokeView();

                m_vwExpandButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        Log.e("tah", "onClick");
                    if(m_vwExpandButton.getText().equals(JokeView.EXPAND)){ 
                            expandJokeView();           
                        }
                        else              
                                  if(m_vwExpandButton.getText().equals(JokeView.COLLAPSE)){
                            collapseJokeView();
                    }
                            }
                });
            m_vwLikeGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rg, int i) {
                        if(i==1){
                            m_joke.setRating(Joke.LIKE);
                        }
                        else if(i==2){
                            m_joke.setRating(Joke.DISLIKE);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }

        public void setJoke(Joke joke) {
            if(joke!=null){
                m_joke=joke;
                m_vwJokeText.setText(joke.getJoke());
                switch(joke.getRating()){
                case Joke.LIKE:
                    m_vwLikeButton.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case Joke.DISLIKE:
                    m_vwDislikeButton.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case Joke.UNRATED:
                    m_vwLikeGroup.clearCheck();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void expandJokeView() {
            m_vwJokeText.setEllipsize(null);
            m_vwJokeText.setSingleLine(false);
            m_vwLikeGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                m_vwExpandButton.setText(JokeView.COLLAPSE);
            this.requestLayout();
        }

        private void collapseJokeView() {
            m_vwJokeText.setSingleLine(true);
            m_vwJokeText.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            m_vwLikeGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            m_vwExpandButton.setText(JokeView.EXPAND);
            this.requestLayout();
        }
    }
```

But onClick happens when I click on button

Comment: It's not possible, unless you specify the onClick attribute in the <Button> declaration. Check again

Comment: I set focusable,clickable,focusableInTouchMode "false" ,but Button's method onClick works

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague. But I suspect since you haven't provided an onClick method for the button click to call, it's defaulting to the only one it can find. Try this:

`android:onClick="expandButtonClicked"`

Then provide a method for the compiler to find.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, when you set **m_vwExpandButton.setOnClickListener** it becomes clickable!

**Description from official documentation:**

setOnClickListener - Register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. **If this view is not clickable, it becomes clickable.**

Comment: But Button will doesn't receive focus.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this lab, and I've solved your problem.
And here's mine

```
package edu.calpoly.android.lab3;
```

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class JokeView extends LinearLayout implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener
{
    private Button m_vwExpandButton;
    private RadioButton m_vwLikeButton;
    private RadioButton m_vwDislikeButton;
    private RadioGroup m_vwLikeGroup;
    private TextView m_vwJokeText;
    private Joke m_joke;

```
public static final String EXPAND = " + ";
public static final String COLLAPSE = " - ";

/**
 * Basic Constructor that takes only takes in an application Context.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            The application Context in which this view is being added. 
 *            
 * @param joke
 *            The Joke this view is responsible for displaying.
 */
public JokeView(Context context, Joke joke) {
    super(context);

    // Inflate
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
              Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.joke_view, this, true);

    // Initialize
    m_vwExpandButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.expandButton);
    m_vwLikeButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.likeButton);
    m_vwDislikeButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.dislikeButton);
    m_vwLikeGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.ratingRadioGroup);
    m_vwJokeText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.jokeTextview);

    // Set joke
    this.setJoke(joke);

    // Set default state
    JokeView.this.collapseJokeView();
    // Event
    m_vwExpandButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (m_vwExpandButton.getText().equals(JokeView.EXPAND))
                JokeView.this.expandJokeView();
            else if (m_vwExpandButton.getText().equals(JokeView.COLLAPSE))
                JokeView.this.collapseJokeView();
        }
    });

    // Radio Group
    m_vwLikeGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(JokeView.this);
}

/**
 * Mutator method for changing the Joke object this View displays. This View
 * will be updated to display the correct contents of the new Joke.
 * 
 * @param joke
 *            The Joke object which this View will display.
 */
public void setJoke(Joke joke) {
    m_joke = joke;
    m_vwJokeText.setText(joke.getJoke());

    if (joke.getRating() == Joke.LIKE)
        m_vwLikeButton.setChecked(true);
    if (joke.getRating() == Joke.DISLIKE)
        m_vwDislikeButton.setChecked(true);
}

/**
 * This method encapsulates the logic necessary to update this view so that
 * it displays itself in its "Expanded" form: 
 *  - Shows the complete text of the joke. 
 *  - Brings the RadioGroup of rating Buttons back into view.
 */
private void expandJokeView() {
    m_vwJokeText.setEllipsize(null);
    m_vwExpandButton.setText(JokeView.COLLAPSE);
    m_vwLikeGroup.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    JokeView.this.requestLayout();
}

/**
 * This method encapsulates the logic necessary to update this view so that
 * it displays itself in its "Collapsed" form: 
 *  - Shows only the first line of text of the joke. 
 *  - If the joke is longer than one line, it appends an ellipsis to the end. 
 *  - Removes the RadioGroup of rating Buttons from view.
 */
private void collapseJokeView() {
    m_vwJokeText.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
    m_vwExpandButton.setText(JokeView.EXPAND);
    m_vwLikeGroup.setVisibility(GONE);
    JokeView.this.requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
{
    if (group.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == m_vwLikeButton.getId())
        m_joke.setRating(Joke.LIKE);
    if (group.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == m_vwDislikeButton.getId())
        m_joke.setRating(Joke.DISLIKE);     
}
```

}